# Create an anaconda environment with an specific installed Python interpreter

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm using anaconda for manage my Python's environments and I want to create an env with a python executable file as interpreter. I didn't find similar question on other topic.

To be more precise, I don't want to create an env like this :

```
conda create --name my_env python=3.6.9
```

I want to create an env with a pre-installed python interpreter, tell to anaconda where to find the python executable file in my machine (in my case `/usr/bin/python3`) and use it as the interpreter for the env. Is it possible?

Comment: Open Anaconda then click on Environment then click bellow in create  and in opened popup select your python version. But version is name like `3.6` or `3.7` not `3.x.x`.

Comment: Look this [Adding Python/R in Jupyter using anaconda (Ubuntu)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQMVrkO99Ec)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can imagine accomplishing this would be to make your own build of the `python` package. Perhaps having a look at [how Conda Forge does this](https://github.com/conda-forge/python-feedstock) might be informative, though you can likely do a very trimmed down version depending on where you expect to run it.

Otherwise, no, not possible, AFAIK.